# Using literary present when there's a sequence of events

Tags: present-tense, writing, literature

I heard that when describing a piece of literature in writing, we should always use the literary present tense.
I am encountering a special situation, where an event takes place after a different event.

(a)

> Tobe continues to stay with Miss Emily even after she murdered Homer
>   Barron and slept with his corpse.

(b)

> Tobe continues to stay with Miss Emily even after she murders Homer
>   Barron and sleeps with his corpse.

I am not sure which sentence above demonstrates the correct use of literary present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first works better if you're describing the reaction (or lack of reaction) to an event that took place in an earlier work in a series, because it shifts into past tense partway through. In other words, if in Book 1 this unsavory event takes place, and Book 2 covers Tobe's perspective rather than another character's, this would be workable. It's also possible, but awkward, to use it if you've just described the event in more detail and are then building on that description for contrast.

However, the second form is really the ideal; the whole thing is in literary present, and the order of events is preserved by using "after" rather than shifting into past tense. There's no confusion for anyone used to reading this style.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix the present and present perfect:

> Tobe **continues to stay** with Miss Emily even after she **has murdered** Homer
>   Barron and slept with his corpse.